# Android - onOptionsItemSelected item ids dont match

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have this method to share an a post. Here is my method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        Log.d(itemId + "", R.id.action_settings + "");

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (itemId == R.id.action_settings) {
           sharePost();
            Log.d("adsfsadf", "sadf");
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The problem is `itemId` and `R.id.action_settings` don't match, so the share isn't called I am not sure why they are not matching here is my xml of the item.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And here is what is logged by this statement

```
Log.d(itemId + "", R.id.action_settings + "");
D/2131230785﹕ 2131230786
```

Thanks for the help in advance!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

```
if (itemId == R.id.action_settings)
```

to

```
if (itemId == R.id.action_share)
```

The problem is that in the `menu.xml` you have set the ID to `action_share` and in java you are checking for a id match of `action_settings`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

your item id is `R.id.action_share` and you are comparing with `R.id.action_settings`, how will it match boss?? it should be

```
if (itemId == R.id.action_share){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to chage this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_share)
    {
        sharePost();
        Log.d("adsfsadf", "sadf");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```